PIC16F15244 Page Size
I'm trying to understand how paging works in PIC microcontrollers. I've worked with S08 and Atmel microcontrollers in the past, but I am completely new to PICs. I thought I understood paging, but I'm having a real hard time finding the page size in the datasheet. On page 108 of the datasheet for the PIC16F15244, it says program memory is arranged in "rows" of thirty-two 14-bit words. Is a "row" the same thing as a page? Am I correct to say this PIC uses 64 byte pages? Thanks for your help!

A page is 1024 word wide and can be accesed with one assembler instruction, because the PC ist only 10bite wide. For further jumps do you need the PCLATHregister. Please have a look:https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/104332/pic-microcontroller-jumping-pages/104388#104388


Is a "row" the same thing as a page?

Yes because both refer to the smallest unit of program memory that can be written to in a single write operation.

Am I correct to say this PIC uses 64 byte pages?

Almost correct, your math is a tad off.

32 rows times 14 bits per word is 448 bits.
448 bits divided by 8 bits per byte is 56 bytes.

You would be correct if the words were 16-bit.

Perfect, thanks very much! For some context: I'm trying to configure a programmer that requires me to set the page size. I believe it treats words as two 8 bit bytes, even though they're actually 14 bits, because all the other pre-configured microcontrollers have page sizes that are powers of two.

Section 15.1 (on page 108 of the data sheet) is referring to non-volatile-memory. This description is limited to how the program memory space is mapped. Mapping is awkward because program words are 14-bit entities, while the CPU itself uses 8-bit entities.
I believe the section you refer to on page 108 is this one:

It is important to understand the program memory structure for erase
and programming operations. Program memory is arranged in rows. A row
consists of 32 14-bit program memory words. A row is the minimum size
that can be erased by user software.

The actual mapping of 14-bit "words" to the 8-bit registers NVMDATH and NVMDATL is well-described in figure 15-4 on page 114 of the data sheet. This figure also shows address-space addressing.

<br

Is a "row" the same thing as a page?

Figure 15-4 does not mention "page", but does mention "row". There are ten bits of row address mapped between NVMADRH and NVMADRL in Figure 15-4. I think the term "page" might refer to something else. PICs often refer to "bank", which is similar to the concept of paging.
